# Treeview nodes export to excel

Tags: c#, excel, forms, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview with several nodes, how can I export my treeview with all child nodes to excel. The progress so far is the below code.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"treeview2.csv"))
foreach (TreeNode node in treeView2.Nodes)
{
  sw.WriteLine(node);
}
```

`

How I would like my output to be this is a pic from online

[Output click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8acN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is using the [EPPlus nuget package](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to create excel files. You could use the Excel Interop as an alternative if you didn't want to use this package.

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TreeView Export");
int rowCounter = 0;

RecurseNodes(treeView1.Nodes, 1);

void RecurseNodes(TreeNodeCollection currentNode, int col)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in currentNode)
    {
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1;
        worksheet.Cells[rowCounter, col].Value = node.Text;
        if (node.FirstNode != null)
            RecurseNodes(node.Nodes, col + 1);
    }
}

excel.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\ProgramData\export.xlsx"));
```

Happy to provide further explanation if required.

Comment: When i run it  its working fine but for some reason its not writing anything to the text file.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Wrap it in a try catch and see if there's any errors.

Comment: Nvm got it to work!! i made some changes to your code but i forgot to close the Streamwriter.  But converting to excel file is gonna be a mess im not even sure how to start any advice?

Comment: I have updated my answer to export to excel file using the EPPlus nuget package.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!! you are amazing!! I have been searching for this answer for couple days now. You are the first person that provided a legitimate answer to export treeview to excel out of all the other forums in the internet. Im pretty sure this will help many other programmers who struggle to understand recursive function which deals with trees